Hi, I developed a To-Do-App project in React JS and Tailwind CSS. When I host the site in Netlify I get some error
6:45:05 PM: **Build** command from Netlify app                                
6:45:05 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
6:45:05 PM: 6:45:05 PM: $ npm run build
6:45:05 PM: > todolist@1.0.0 build
**6:45:05 PM: > parcel build index.html
6:45:05 PM:   No entries found.
6:45:05 PM:     at Bundler.bundle (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/parcel-bundler/src/Bundler.js:275:17)**
6:45:06 PM: ​
6:45:06 PM: "build.command" failed       

                             

How to Host this project
